# Alocamento dinâmico/estocástico de objectos em QML

Tags: qt, random, qml

Estou de momento a tentar fazer o seguinte em **QML**, em simultâneo:

- fazer **loading dinâmico de objects** previamente criados um ficheiro à parte;
- ao fazer aquilo que é anteriormente aqui descrito, **seleccionar os objectos estocasticamente**

Para isso estou, muito basicamente, a usar o código abaixo:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: randomMIDIkeyboardSelector;
    property var random: 0;

    function randomSelection(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      var out = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      console.log(parseFloat(out));
      return parseFloat(out);
    }

    function createMidiKeyboard(itemToBeInstantiated) {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("MidiKeyboard.qml");
        var midiKeyboard = component.createObject(itemToBeInstantiated, {});
    }

    function randomPicking() {
        random = parseInt(randomSelection(1, 8));
        if(random == 1) {createMidiKeyboard(MidiKeyboard);}
        if(random == 2) {createMidiKeyboard(MidiKeyboard2);}
        if(random == 3) {createMidiKeyboard(MidiKeyboard3);}
        if(random == 4) {createMidiKeyboard(MidiKeyboard4);}
        if(random == 5) {createMidiKeyboard(MidiKeyboard5);}
        if(random == 6) {createMidiKeyboard(MidiKeyboard6);}
        if(random == 7) {createMidiKeyboard(MidiKeyboard7);}
        if(random == 8) {createMidiKeyboard(Midikeyboard8);}
        return random;
    }

    Component.onCompleted: randomPicking();

}
```

Basicamente, estou **a criar um número aleatório e a usar uma função de javascript para criar objectos dinamicamente**, que instancio a partir de um `if statement`

Contudo, quando carrego o ficheiro no documento principal, **o objecto de user interface desejado não é criado na janela**

Para perceberem melhor o teor conteúdo do projecto **sugiro, caso tenham interesse, que consultem o link abaixo:**

https://github.com/tiagmoraismorgado/TMM_QML_UI_UX_FRAMEWORK_WIP

Comment: Luiz Vieira, obrigado pelo edit.

Comment: Por nada Tiago. :) Bem vindo ao SOPT. Retirei as saudações porque este site não é um fórum. Infelizmente não uso QML, então não sei mesmo responder à sua pergunta. Mas outros saberão! Boa sorte!

Comment: já agora, fica a sugestão, para quem quiser dar uma vista de olhos no framework me funcionamento, segue o link com o video abaixo https://vimeo.com/188973909

Comment: Tiago, isso significa que você conseguiu resolver a sua dificuldade? Se sim, não deixe de responder você mesmo à pergunta, pois assim pode ajudar outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema no futuro.

Comment: não, luiz, ainda não consegui dar resposta ao problema. obrigado pela dica :)

Comment: Ah, ok. Enquanto isso, dá uma lida [neste tópico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) da ajuda a respeito do que fazer se demorar pra ter respostas. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1º tens de dar uma tamanho ao componente

2º A operação createComponent é assíncrona por defeito. Por isso tens de esperar que o componente seja carregado.

3º É preciso definir a path relativa ou absoluta dos componentes que queres carregar porque estão em pastas/caminhos diferentes.

Aqui fica o meu fix:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: randomMIDIkeyboardSelector;
    anchors.fill: parent  // fit item size to parent size 
    property var random: 0;

    function randomSelection(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        var out = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        console.log(parseFloat(out));
        return parseFloat(out);
    }

    function createMidiKeyboard(itemToBeInstantiated) {
        var component = Qt.createComponent(itemToBeInstantiated)
        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            console.log("Component created with success!! ")
            var midiKeyboard = component.createObject(randomMIDIkeyboardSelector, {});
        }
        else if (component.status === Component.Error) {
            console.log("Error loading component: ", component.errorString())
        }
    }

    function randomPicking() {
        random = parseInt(randomSelection(1, 8));
        if(random == 1) {createMidiKeyboard("qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard.qml");}
        if(random == 2) {createMidiKeyboard("qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard2.qml");}
        if(random == 3) {createMidiKeyboard("qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard3.qml");}
        if(random == 4) {createMidiKeyboard("qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard4.qml");}
        if(random == 5) {createMidiKeyboard("qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard5.qml");}
        if(random == 6) {createMidiKeyboard("qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard6.qml");}
        if(random == 7) {createMidiKeyboard("qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard7.qml");}
        if(random == 8) {createMidiKeyboard("qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/Midikeyboard8.qml");}
        return random;
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        randomPicking();
    }

}
```

Adicionalmente também precisei de adicionar no ficheiro principal (instantiationTest.qml) os seguintes imports:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import "qrc:/_files_qml/_Buttons/"
import "qrc:/_files_qml/_MIDIKeyboards/"
import "qrc:/_files_qml/_Stochastic Selectors/"

Window {
  ....
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: ajudou sim, luigi. em relação ao primeiro bloco de código, tudo bom. em relação ao segundo, parti o projecto em directorias, já depois de ter criado este post, o que acabou por fazer com que, de alguma forma, o projecto ficasse com erros. alias estou com problemas em compilar, mesmo depois de ter adicionado os ficheiros, quer da forma com que o fizeste, quer da forma com que o fiz. ja experimentei fazer um clean build e um rebuild, andar a modificar definições no ficheiro de configuração do projecto mas não adiantou de muito

Comment: muito grato pela ajuda. com amizade. tiago

Comment: bastou-me criar um projecto novo e copiar para lá os ficheiros, e o problema ficou automaticamente resolvido

Answer (score 0):

no meu caso coloquei o código assim:

import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: randomMIDIkeyboardSelector;
    anchors.fill: parent  // fit item size to parent size
    property var random: 0;

```
function randomSelection(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    var out = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    console.log(parseFloat(out));
    return parseFloat(out);
}

function createMidiKeyboard(itemToBeInstantiated) {
    var component = Qt.createComponent(itemToBeInstantiated)
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        console.log("Component created with success!! ")
        var midiKeyboard = component.createObject(randomMIDIkeyboardSelector, {});
    }
    else if (component.status === Component.Error) {
        console.log("Error loading component: ", component.errorString())
    }
}

function randomPicking() {
    random = parseInt(randomSelection(1, 8));
    if(random == 1) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard.qml");}
    if(random == 2) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard2.qml");}
    if(random == 3) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard3.qml");}
    if(random == 4) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard4.qml");}
    if(random == 5) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard5.qml");}
    if(random == 6) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard6.qml");}
    if(random == 7) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_MIDIKeyboards/MidiKeyboard7.qml");}
    if(random == 8) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_MIDIKeyboards/Midikeyboard8.qml");}
    return random;
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    randomPicking();
}
```

}

import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import "_Buttons/"
import "_MIDIKeyboards/"
import "_StochasticSelectors/"
import "_Sliders/"
import "_imgButtons/"

Window {

```
id: root
width: 640
height: 320
minimumWidth: 640
maximumWidth: 640
minimumHeight: 320
maximumHeight: 320
visible: true
title: qsTr("instantiationTest")
color: "black"

    // Button1 {}            // the button looks good and is working fine, feedback is welcome
    // Button1_1 {}          // the button looks good and is working fine, feedback is welcome
    // Button2 {}            // the button looks good and is working fine, feedback is welcome
    // Button2_2 {}            // the button looks good and is working fine, feedback is welcome
    // Button3 {}            // the button is working fine, but looking terribly. feedback is welcome
    // Button3_3 {}
    // Button4 {}            // the button is working fine, but looking terribly. feedback is welcome
    // Button4_4 {}
    // Slider1 {}            // slider looks good but is buggy and faulty. feedback is welcome
    // Toggle1 {}            // toggle looks good nad is working fine. feedback is welcome
    // Toggle2 {}            // toggle looks good nad is working fine. feedback is welcome
    // Radial {}             // radial looks good and is working fine. feedback is welcome
    // Switch {}             // switch works fine. images need to be treated in photoshop, to keep black background and same size. feedback is welcome
    // UpDownArrows {}       // working and looking fine. needs some twweaking within dimensions cropping
    // PlayStop {}           // looks and works perfectly.feedback is welcome, however
    // Click1 {}             // looks and works perfectly. needs mouseX and mouseY coordinates
    // Click2 {}             // looks and works perfectly. needs mouseX and mouseY coordinates
    // MidiKeyboard {}
    // MidiKeyboard2 {}
    // MidiKeyboard4 {}
    // MidiKeyboard5 {}
    // MidiKeyboard6 {}
    // MidiKeyboard7 {}
    // Midikeyboard8 {}
    // MidiKeyboardRandomSelect {}
    // ButtonStochasticSelector {}
    // ToggleStochasticSelector {}
    // MasterStochasticallocation {}
```

}